# Storing Custom Object in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to store a custom object in NSMutableDictionary. After saving when I read the object from NSMutableDictionary it's always null.

Here is the code

//Saving

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

CustomObject *obj1 = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
obj1.property1 = @"My First Property";

[dict setObject:obj1 forKey:@"FirstObjectKey"];
[dict writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

// Reading

```
 NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        CustomObject *tempObj = [dict objectForKey:@"FirstObjectKey"];

        NSLog(@"Object %@", tempObj);
        NSLog(@"property1:%@,,tempObj.property1);
```

How can I store a custom class object in NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: What does the NSLog output tell you? And can you read the file to verify that your object is getting written to it correctly?

Comment: 2011-04-11 19:31:14.386 Persistence[1757:207] Object (null)
2011-04-11 19:31:14.388 Persistence[1757:207] property1:(null)

Comment: `-[NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:]` returns a `BOOL`. Did it occur to you to check the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writeToFile` method can store only standard types of objects into plist. If you have custom object you'd have to use `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver` for this.

Comment: Hi Eimantas, I have implemented NSKeyedArchiver approach and I can save custom object now. My question is can I use this like nsdictionary. I mean in NSDictionary there is built in function to get all keys so you can ecumerate through. Can I enumerate through archived objects aswel?

Comment: Not really unless you archive the dictionary with your object (i.e. use encodeWithCoder instead of writeToFile).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not with putting the object into the dictionary; the problem is with writing it to a file.

Your custom class has to be [serializable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE). You need to implement the [`NSCoding` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) so that Cocoa knows what to do with your class when you ask for it to be written out to disk.

This is pretty simple to do; you need to implement two methods that will look something like the following:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    // If inheriting from a class that implements initWithCoder:
    // self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    myFirstIvar = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myFirstIvar] retain];
    mySecondIvar = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"mySecondIvar] retain];
    // etc.

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    // If inheriting from a class that implements encodeWithCoder:
    // [super encodeWithCoder:coder];
    [coder encodeObject:myFirstIvar forKey:@"myFirstIvar"];
    [coder encodeObject:mySecondIvar forKey:@"mySecondIvar"];
    // etc.
}
```

Essentially you're just listing the ivars that you need to save, and then reading them back in properly.

UPDATE: As mentioned by Eimantas, you'll also need `NSKeyedArchiver`. To save:

```
NSData * myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myDict];
BOOL result = [myData writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

To reload:

```
NSData * myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
NSDictionary * myDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: Hi Josh, I have implemented the NSCoding and still unable to save the object in dictionary. As Mike mentioned I checked the result from write to file and result is "No". Any idea?

Comment: @Leo: That's right, sorry; Eimantas mentioned the other half of what you need: `NSKeyedArchiver`. I've updated my answer to include that part.